# Hazelcast: Error while fetching cluster partition table

Tags: java, hazelcast

When loading data > 50GB into a Hazelcast Map I get this error message quite reproducible:

"> Error while fetching cluster partition table"

The Client API loses the connection to the cluster frequently. Why does it lose connection , and should Hazelcast not transparently reconnect?

The Hazelcast client API is used with a single node cluster.
Hazelcast max map size: 200 GB, with LRU eviction policy.
Java MaxHeap Size: 400 GB
Version: Hazelcast 3.3

```
    java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:116)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:103)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getPartitionsFrom(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.access$300(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl$RefreshTask.run(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:58)
```

and afterwards

```
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_6_dev][3.3-EA] is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
Jun 17, 2014 5:23:01 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
WARNING: Connection [null] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
Jun 17, 2014 5:23:01 PM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [xxx]:5701 [dev] [3.3-EA] Connection [Address[xxxx]:55496] lost. Reason: java.io.IOException[Broken pipe]
Jun 17, 2014 5:23:01 PM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [xxx]:5701 [dev] [3.3-EA] Connection [Address[127.0.0.1]:60751] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
Jun 17, 2014 5:23:01 PM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngine
```

Comment: did you figure out the solution?

Comment: curious if you uncovered what the issue was - I am seeing the same but with v3.2.4 and I can't figure out whether its the environment or my config file or something else - thanks

Comment: we did not uncover the issue. Probably the issue was related to the huge heap size.